# Express $v$ in terms of $v_0$ and $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The height of a ball is given by $h(t) = x - 16t^2$, where $x$ is the initial height.

A pitcher throws at a velocity $v_0$, then the kinetic energy is: $E_0 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2_0$.

Express $v$ in terms of $v_0$ and $x$ (I can't use $g$ or whatever gravitational information, this isn't a real physics problem).

**My attempt**

We know that $v$ is the derivative of $h$, so $v(t) = -32t$. The pitcher throws at speed $v_0$, so: $v_0 = -32t$ at some time $t$.

We can express $t$ in terms of $x$, but now I'm stuck with some $h$, I can't seem to use. Since $h(t) = x - 16t^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{x - h} = t$.

So $v$ seems to be  $v=-8 \sqrt{x - h}$, can I epxress $h$ in $v_0$? I'm not sure how to proceed and I need this to further solve the problem (and have no way of checking)...